# Are there more than one type of gradient?

Tags: calculus

The lecturer is [saying](https://youtu.be/_9RGpiWjn_o?t=111)

> now the `rise over run` type gradient varies depending on where we choose our points

according to my knowledge `rise over run` is the gradient, they are the same. (may be I am wrong, please feel free to identify or fix the bugs)

So, are there more than one types of gradient?

**Note:** the key is on "type".

Answer (score 1):

There is another type of gradient - and it's in the title of the video!

Derivative. The derivative is a different type of gradient that is NOT rise over run. But rather, a limit of rise over run.

Answer (score -1):

Your instructor is probably saying that for a curve or surface the *value* of the "rise over run" gradient may be different at different places. The definition doesn't change.

(I haven't watched the video.)

Comment: The question is more about the word "type", if I'm reading it correctly.

Comment: I the the speaker is more emphasizing that there are the "rise over run" gradient and the "derivative" gradient. And they are different.

Comment: @user658409 Fair point. I shouldn't answer questions that call for watching a video. I will delete my answer in a while.